# Updating default log4j-over slfj 1.x from spring starter kit to log4j-slf4j-impl-2.0.jar

Tags: java, spring, log4j, log4j2, slf4j

I have an application which uses Spring starter kit 1.4.0. We are using log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25 JAR. We wanted to upgrade to log4j-slf4j-impl-2.0.jar. Can we do this upgrade with the spring version?
Also any guidance on this migration would be really helpful.

Comment: Those libraries have nothing in common: one redirects from Log4j 1.2 to SLF4J, the other from SLF4J to Log4j 2.x. What are you trying to accomplish? `log4j-over-slf4j` is not affected by the recent Log4j 2.x vulnerability.

Comment: Eventhough log4j-over-slf4j is not affected by the vulnerability we have a mandate to upgrade to log4j 2.16. I'm trying to still use logfj via slf4j with the underlying version of log4j as the latest. Is there any other options of using log4j 2.16 with slf4j?

Comment: Can you add your logging dependencies? `spring-boot-starter-logging` uses Logback as a backend. On the other hand `spring-boot-starter-log4j2` does not depend on `log4j-over-slf4j`. Therefore I am not convinced that you log through Log4j 2. x.

Comment: Just to update on this. Have done this update to log4j 2.16 instead of including slf4j. Also had to update the spring version from 1.4.0 to 2.3.7